# MySQL Sum and case

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a query wherein I would count how many awards does an applicant have. So far I have this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Award1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
as summedColumn
FROM resume, person
where E_Status = 'Applicant' 
and person.ID_No like 'x' and resume.ID_No like 'x'

Table:Person                         Values
ID_No(Varchar, Primary)              x
F_Name(Varchar)                      Fasa
L_Name(Varchar)                      Bel
M_Name(Varchar)                      Drake
Resume_ID(Varchar)                   res01

Table: Resume                        Value
Resume_ID(Varchar, Primary)          res01
ID_No(Varchar)                       x
Award1(Varchar)                      Suma Cum Laude
Award2(Varchar)                      null
Award3(Varchar)                      null
Award4(Varchar)                      null
Past_Position1(Varchar)              HR manager
Past_Position2(Varchar)              null

Output of the query: 4
```

When I ran the code it returned a value of 4 but my Award2, Award3 and Award4 are all null. The code suppose to return a value of 1.

Here is the look of the table:

Comment: you don't have a join clause in the query.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you are having multiple 'Award' columns? What does the database structure look like?

Comment: Post the output of "select * FROM resume, person
where E_Status = 'Applicant' and person.ID_No like 'x' and resume.ID_No like 'x'"  so we can see the actual data.

Comment: Maybe those columns are empty string and not really NULL

Comment: Avoid using ANSI-89 `JOIN`s. Use ANSI-92 style instead. This is not only more verbose and expressive, but also separates your `JOIN` logic from your filtering logic. This may be your problem.

Comment: @user3797088 This is not what I'mlooking for.  as others have brought up, there is most likely a cross join happening because your join logic is unclear.  we need to see the structure and data of both the resume and person tables, as well as the ouput of the query I posted above.

Comment: @PhilipDevine Like that?

Comment: Where is the E_status column? And both of your tables only have 1 row? we need to see the actual output of running "select * FROM resume, person where E_Status = 'Applicant' and person.ID_No like 'x' and resume.ID_No like 'x'" , not your approximation of the data.  If you want to munge specific values that's ok, but leave the ID's intact.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't join your two tables, so it is making a cross join between Resume and Person tables.

Find the key which relates Person to Resume, and equals them together:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Award1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Award4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
as summedColumn
FROM resume 
    INNER JOIN person
        ON resume.Resume_ID = person.Resume_ID
where E_Status = 'Applicant' 
and person.ID_No like 'x' and resume.ID_No like 'x'
```

Comment: Tried, what I did was resume.Resume_ID = person.Resume_ID on the inner join still the results where the same.

Comment: Sadly no the results were the same

Comment: Can you post a full example of your data in Person and Resume tables for the example you provide?

Comment: That should give you a result of `1` with this set of data. I didn't even see the E_Status in your schema. There is too much VARCHAR, why the keys are not integer? I think there is a lot of problem, not only the query. But for your actual question, the query is ok.

Comment: Yes that is the target but sadly it returned 4. Did not know that this query would be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to rethink your database structure.
How about creating an 1:n structure?

Table structure Person: `ID, Name ...`

Table Structure AwardRel: `PersonID, AwardRel`

Table Structure Awards: `ID, AwardName, ...`

With a 1:n structure like this, your query can be expressed as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `AwardRel` WHERE `PersonID` = 1;
```

This query should return any number of awards Person 1 has ever obtained.